# strongloop loopback how do I serve-static with a route?

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I want to do something like

```
// server.js
app.use('/client', loopback.static(__dirname + '/../client'))
```

using `middleware.json`, but the example only works from the root

```
"files": {
  "loopback#static": {
    "params": "$!../client"
  }
},
```

Comment: Do you mean like `yourdomain.com/custom-route/asset.jpg`? You want to add a route in front of the static assets?

Comment: yes. app.use() seems to work fine, but I'm trying to understand how to use middleware.json fully

Answer (score 6):

You have to use `paths` property, i.e.

```
"files": {
  "loopback#static": {
    "paths": "/client",
    "params": "$!../client"
  }
},
```

The detail is [here](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Defining-middleware.html#static-middleware).

Answer (score 2):

I created a new file *boot/routes.js*

```
var path    = require("path");

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.get('/ping', function(req, res) {
     res.sendFile(pt('client/index.html'));
   });
};

function pt(relative) {
  return path.resolve(__dirname, '../..', relative);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try?

```
"files": {
  "loopback#static": {
    "params": "$!../../client"
  }
}
```