# How to serve static content in Loopback 4.0?

Tags: loopback4

I've found this Q&A on loopback, but it doesn't work for 4.0:
[strongloop loopback how do I serve-static with a route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28628535/strongloop-loopback-how-do-i-serve-static-with-a-route)

I want to serve some basic static content.  Or maybe even arbitrary content.

This is how things usually work with express apps:

```
export class SomeLoopbackApp extends RestApplication {

  constructor() {
    const app = this;
    app.static('/', path.join(__dirname, '../../public'));
    app.get('/hello', (req, res) => {
      res.send('Hello world!')
    });
  }
}
```

For reasons, neither of these work in Loopback 4.  I've tried finding a way to access the actual express instance hidden somewhere in Loopback (I'm pretty sure it uses one), but I can't seem to find it.

How do I make loopback serve static content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am severing static content in loopback 4 the following way.

```
export class InstrideIdentityApiApplication extends BootMixin(
  ServiceMixin(RepositoryMixin(RestApplication))
) {
  this.static('/', path.join(__dirname, '../../public'));
}
```

However, you could run an express server and serve static content from express and then bing loopback 4 and express app together.

https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/express-with-lb4-rest-tutorial.html

Comment: Hmmm... this does not seem to be working.  Is loopback not express based?  Its documentation seems to imply it is.

Answer (score 2):

To serve static files, `this.static()` can be used:

```js
import path from 'path';

export class TodoListApplication extends BootMixin(
  ServiceMixin(RepositoryMixin(RestApplication)),
) {
  constructor(options: ApplicationConfig = {}) {
    super(options);

    // ...

    this.static('/', path.join(__dirname, '../../public'));
  }
}
```

While LoopBack 4 does use Express.js internally to re-use some of its features, it does not expose the entire API under normal circumstances.

There are some bindings under [`RestBindings.Http`](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/apidocs.rest.restbindings.http.html) that can be used to inject the Express.js RequestContext, Request, or Response objects into a controller. However, this should be considered a last resort.

If accessing these bindings are necessary, it is strongly recommended to inject them into a controller to take advantage of the lifecycle management and booters in LoopBack 4:

```js
// /src/controllers/redirect.controller.ts
import {inject} from '@loopback/context';
import {get, Response, RestBindings} from '@loopback/rest';

export class RedirectController {
  constructor(@inject(RestBindings.Http.RESPONSE) private res: Response) {}

  // Map to `GET /redirect`
  @get('/redirect', {
    responses: {
      '302': {
        description: 'Redirect Response',
      },
    },
  })
  redirect(): void {
    this.res.setHeader('x-secret-sauce', 'Sugar, spice and everything nice.');
    this.res.redirect('https://www.example.com/');
  }
}
```

The above code snippet shows how to set a response header and return a redirect. Though any parts of the [Express.js Response API](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res) can be used.

Further reading:

- https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Serving-static-files.html
- [How to set a different Http Status in loopback 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54655257/how-to-set-a-different-http-status-in-loopback-4)

Comment: I tried this, but it seems that returning html responses is not straight-forward.  Put in an issue about it: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/4321

Comment: @SephReed FYI, `strongloop/loopback` is for LoopBack 3 which is going to EOL in December 2020.

Issues related to LoopBack 4 must be opened in `strongloop/loopback-next`.

Also, it is strongly recommended to use the CLI to scaffold the application. This would make the issue more easily solvable and reproducible.